# Connvert Continuous data to categorical data in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numeric, categorical-data, continuous

All,

I have below dataset and I Would like to add one extra column to my dataframe, that will represent/reflect the outcome in categorical data as below.

**Current Dataset** :[image]

**After adding new column:**
[image]

Please advise on how to approach this.I'm new to pyton if you can provide the explanation, that will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `map` after create the `dict` , but let us try something new

```
pd.cut(df.Seasons,4,labels=['Winter','Spring','Summer','Fall'])
Out[262]: 
0    Winter
1    Spring
2    Summer
3      Fall
4    Summer
dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Winter < Spring < Summer < Fall]
```

Ok Using map

```
d=dict(zip([1,2,3,4],['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']))
df.Seasons.map(d)
Out[265]: 
0    Winter
1    Spring
2    Summer
3      Fall
4    Summer
dtype: object
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to show another approach that you talked about i.e creating Dictionary and than Mapping ?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that approach suggested by Conner generated similar results. The only difference is that data type. If I used your first approach, then datatype will be 'Category', but if I use another approach suggested by Conner or You. The datatype is Object. I'm trying to understand the difference between two.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

> data.csv

```
Age,Population,Seasons
20,100,1
30,340,2
35,45,3
40,90,4
45,9,3
```

> test.py

```
#!/bin/python

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

seasons = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']

df['Seas_Fact'] = [seasons[x-1] for x in df['Seasons']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Age  Population  Seasons Seas_Fact
0   20         100        1    Winter
1   30         340        2    Spring
2   35          45        3    Summer
3   40          90        4      Fall
4   45           9        3    Summer
```

Comment: Thanks Conner! Please see my comment with W-B.I'm trying to understand the difference between Object and Category. The code you suggested, generated my desired output, however it generated 'Object' datatype. Where as pandas Cut generated the data type category. What could be the reason  ?

Comment: If you want the categorical datatype you can cast it with `df['Seas_Fact'] = df['Seas_Fact'].astype('category')`